# Molecular formula of a compund

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas, molecules, chemical-compounds

I have no idea on how to get information out of this one.

> A compound contains only hydrogen and nitrogen. Nitrogen makes up for 87.4% of the mass. A sample of this have a density of 0.977 g/L at 740 torr and 100 C. What is the molecular formula of the compound?

The best I could think of was to put  it in $PV=nRT$, so $n=PV/RT$. But since there is no defined volume I can't put in anything for $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of masses is 7:1 in the compound but Nitrogen has 14 times the mass of Hydrogen as single atoms so there must be twice as many Hydrogen atoms as Nitrogen atoms i.e. the formula must be NH_2

Comment: But the answers in the back of the book says it's supposed to be N_2H_4.

Comment: To distinguish between NH$_2$ and N$_2$H$_4$, you may be able to use the given info about the properties of the substance and a table of such properties.

Comment: But since pressure is directly related to the amount of mols in the container, shouldn't there be a way to check if 0.977 g/L corresponds to 740 torr and get some information out of that?

Comment: Yes! You can probably manipulate the ideal gas law so that mass density $m/V$ comes out.

Comment: But thats my problem, I don't know how to build further from this. I just get some ideas, but no clue on how to put it all togheter